# format '%lld' expects type 'long long int', but argument 4 has type 'int64_t'

Tags: c, linux

I try to print a variable of type `int64_t` using `%lld` format specifier but get the following warning?

> Warning: format '%lld' expects type 'long long int', but argument 4
>   has type 'int64_t'

In my opinion, under linux, the `int64_t` is always `long long int`, then:

1. Why does this warning occur?
2. How can I fix this?

Comment: *In my opinion, under linux, the `int64_t` is always `long long int`.* Actually, there is no guarantee that will *always* be the case.

Comment: Even more, since the compiler complained about the `printf` format, it most likely isn't `long long` on your platform but `long`.

Comment: Do not program by opinion, prejudice, superstition, belief, or a-colleague-told-me-to. Instead, 1) learn where the rules are, 2) learn the rules, 3) follow the rules.

Comment: To make this clear: on 64-bit Linux systems, `int64_t` will have type `long int`, not `long long int`.

Answer (score 27):

> how to fix?

Use `PRId64`: (Don't forget to include [`<inttypes.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer))

```
printf("var64 = %" PRId64 "\n", var64);
```

Use `PRIx64` and proper cast if you want to print it as hex.

> `int64_t` is always `long long int`, then why does this warning occur?

C99 onwards ([link to draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), Page 22), C specs suggest the type `long long int` should be **atleast** 64 bits but it may be more also.

> — minimum value for an object of type long long int
>  LLONG_MIN
>   -9223372036854775807 // −(2<sup>63</sup>−1)
>  — maximum value for an object of type long long int
>  LLONG_MAX +9223372036854775807 //
>   2<sup>63</sup>− 1

On some platforms, `long long int` might be 128-bit and the print statement invokes [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) on such platforms.

So treat this warning as a portability issue warning.

Comment: Note that on 64-bit Linux `long long int` has 64 bits; however, `int64_t` is still a `long int` not a `long long int` so gcc warns about using the `%lld` format specifier because it doesn't match the type (even though they have the same underlying representation).

Comment: good to note that! My experience is that with Clang on MacOS/Darwin (64bit) the compiler does expect us to use `%lld` for `int64_t` (there is another warning for that otherwise ... :D). However, on Linux x64 it causes the above warning. So the only way to get this right indeed would be `PRId64`, thanks for this answer! But as you mentioned, in both cases the behavior will be fine even with %lld, as `%lld` is 64 bits as well (on the archs used here).